# Difference between SIOCGIFCONF and NETLINK protocol results when enumerating IPv6 addresses on Linux

Tags: linux, ip, ipv6, ioctl

'ifconfig' relies on SIOCGIFCONF to enumerate the IP addresses on the Linux machine, but it seems to return different set of IPv6 addresses than the output of 'ip addr show', which relies on NETLINK protocol.

Development for 'ifconfig' seems to have been frozen since 2001, while NETLINK appears to be a newer protocol for general IP address management on Linux.

The question is: is there any difference in Linux kernel that would cause SIOCGIFCONF ioctl to return different results for IPv6 addresses compared to NETLINK protocol?

Comment: Example?  `RTM_GETADDR` can provide IP family filtered output thus skipping many devices.

Comment: `SIOCGIFCONF` is the older method, but also the only one that's portable outside of Linux. I do not know for sure, but, being older, I expect it has a lot of legacy baggage like treating addresses as 'primary' and 'secondary' instead of just a flat list, and perhaps it is unable to see some of the fancier IPv6 attributes of the addresses (like preferred/valid lifetime) at all. You should probably just use netlink if you're confining yourself to Linux.